# How to check current MTU value

Tags: networking

How can I check the MTU value for my current connection?

In my network connection settings, the MTU is set to **automatic** and I would like to know wich value was automatic selected for it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
ifconfig
```

to view the current MTU. Example (just searching for MTU):

```
ifconfig| grep -i MTU
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Answer (score 55):

Alternative method:

```
ip addr | grep mtu
```

For example:

```
 ip addr | grep mtu
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1300 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
4: veth0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
```

Comment: Trying to avoid a pure "+1!" response, but this alternate answer deserves some love in modern environments where containerization means the running OS of an application may be stripped of common networking tools, like `ipconfig`.

Comment: @firo can you please write `ip addr` instead of `ip ad`. While abbreviation is possible, I think it's better to use full name in answers.

Comment: @marcbollinger `ipconfig` may be "common", but it's also deprecated - the real reason for it being stripped out IMO :) It can omit important information at times, such as secondary IPs; IIRC the method it uses to communicate with the kernel (ioctls) limits the amount of data that can be sent, while the tools in `iproute2` use a different method (netlink) with far higher limits.

Answer (score 28):

You can read the value from the `/sys` kernel file system:

```
cat /sys/class/net/<interface>/mtu
```

Replace `<interface>` with the name of the interface to query.

Comment: Only this answer of all three worked for me when I needed to check the MTU value on a remote server where issuing both `ifconfig` and `ip` commands resulted in message `command not found`.

Comment: The numbers here seems to be more correct than what `ip` shows. `ip` gives `maxmtu` whereas the number in this file seems to show the actual `mtu`. I think.